# NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I get these errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/project.1stApp.youtubeplayer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

When I'm trying to run my application, this 'com.google.gson' library is a jar file that I did added to my project and can't understand when I have this problems..

No code added as I find it not relevent to the error...

Comment: What IDE are you using, and how did you try to add it?

Comment: @EricS. using Android Studio lastest version, added the jar file through Project Structure.

Answer (score 6):

Copy jar into your libs folder and add this to your build.gradle dependencies

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

(Exchange 2.3.1 for your version of json, or use 2.3.*)

Dont forget to sync

Comment: I will try that and update, thanks! Update: I tried, already have this lines. Any other way to solve this?

Comment: With Android Studio 2.1, just download the jar and put it in your libs folder.

Do NOT also add the compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' also!

Answer (score 1):

I use AS.I meet the same problem when I generated signed apk and I do add gson.jar as library.Then i clean the project the problem gone;

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the jar is in the `libs` folder and then right-click and hit  `Add as Library`. You also must have `compile files('jarname.jar')` in the gradle build file. After that, run a gradle clean and try building again.

Comment: Thanks. I did added the jar file and I do have the 'compile files' line, I have few more .jar files I added and no problem with them. What should I do know? It is stopping me from progress as I can't find any solution.

Comment: Please post gradle build file, directory structure and full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem, I had to update something and get another JAR.